# Showing DropDown list in twitter bootstrap doesn't work correctly 

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two drop down list using twitter bootstrap, but I have a small problem .. when choosing the menu , the sub items appears , bu then in the next time don't .
Html code :

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills left">

                        <li class="dropdown" id="menu1">

                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="color:#fff;" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu1"><i class="icon icon-user icon-white">
                            </i> My Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="OldReports.aspx">Previouse Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Profile.aspx">My Profile</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnLogout" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ForeColor="Black">Log out</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                            <li class="dropdown active" id="menu2">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu2"><span class="badge-notification badge badge-error">
                              <asp:Label ID="lblMsgCount" CssClass="lblMsgCount" runat="server" Text=".."></asp:Label></span> 
                            <i class="icon icon-envelope icon-white">
                            </i> Notificatons  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul ID="divNewNotifications" class="dropdown-menu">

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
```

JavaScript code :

```
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

and included the required lib.

```
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is the code on http://jsfiddle.net/zNVgq/2/

Comment: It's possible that you must create two <ul>?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue over at http://jsfiddle.net? also, you don't really need the js call for the dropdowns to function.

Comment: @AndresIlich here is the code on http://jsfiddle.net/zNVgq/1/

Comment: Your code on the fiddle is different from what is show above? I've updated it so it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/zNVgq/3/

Comment: whats you have changed ?

Comment: @Bader everything works fine for me in your fiddle. What bootstrap plugins are you including in your page? Are you including the `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap-dropdown.js` at the same time (only the `bootstrap.js` script file is needed)?